# proving unbiasedness of an estimator

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation

**Question**
given independent random variable $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$ from a geometric distribution with parameter $p$. we have an estimator for $p$, mainly $T=Y/n$ where Y is number of $i$ that  $X_{i}=1 $. show that estimator $T$ is an unbiased estimator.

I know that an unbiased estimator is an estimator when $E[T]=\Theta$  where $\Theta$ is the parameter of interest, so here we are interested in $p$.  answer is given to this exercise but for me is very unclear, I would appreciate if somebody could clarify for me.

here is the **Solution**

> $nT$ has a bionomial distribution with parameter $p$. the expectation of $nT$ is thus $np$. so $T$ is unbiased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if your estimator is consistent, you want to, as you said, compute $\mathbb{E}[T]$. In your case that is
$$
\mathbb{E}[T] = \mathbb{E}[Y/n] = \frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}[Y].
$$
Now $Y$ is the is number of $i$ that $X_i=1$, or, equivalently, $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{X_i=1}$, where $\mathbb{1}_E$ denotes the indicator function of an event $E$, i.e.
$$
\mathbb{1}_{E}=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if $E$ occurs,} \\ 0 & \text{if $E$ doesn't occur}\end{cases}.
$$

This implies, since the expectation of a sum is the sum of expectations (linearity) that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}[Y] = \frac1n\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{X_i=1}\right] = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{X_i=1}].
$$
It remains to compute $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{X_i=1}]$ which is the same for each $i$ since the $X_i$ all have the same distribution.

The probability distribution of the random variable $\mathbb{1}_{X_i=1}$ is
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{1}_{X_i=1}=0) = \mathbb{P}(X_i\neq1),\quad \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{1}_{X_i=1}=1) = \mathbb{P}(X_i=1).
$$

To proceed from here, you will have to specify what version of the geometric distribution you are working with: Is it supported on $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ or $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$?

Assuming the latter, it follows that $\mathbb{P}(X_i\neq1)=1-p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=p$ and thus
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{X_i=1}] = 0\times(1-p) + 1\times p=p
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[T]=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^np=\frac1n np = p.
$$

This shows that your estimator is consistent.

To clarify the answer that you're given you should observe that the $\mathbb{1}_{X_i=1}$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$. Thus $nT$ is the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli random variables, and such a sum is known to follow a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$. A binomial distribution $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$ with parameters $n$ and $p$ has indeed expectation $np$, and thus
$$
\mathbb{E}[nT] = np,
$$
or, by the linearity of $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$, $\mathbb{E}[T]=p$.

Comment: That's true, @did. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: well explained @Eckhard its clear now!

Comment: @Solix, I'm glad that it helped. If you're happy with the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. This will mark your question as answered and help direct people's efforts to yet unanswered questions. The same holds for your other questions.

Comment: @Eckhart: i did it, good to know this feature thx for informing me about it.